# Array Aggregation at Multiple Hierarchies

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Consider the following, fairly standard, de-normalized transaction information model:

```
with transactions as(
  select 'T_10000' as trans_id, 'L_1000' as line_item_id, 'P_100' as part_id
  union all 
  select 'T_10000', 'L_1000', 'P_101'
  union all
  select 'T_10000', 'L_1001', 'P_103'
  union all 
  select 'T_10001', 'L_1002', 'P_104'
)
```

[image: transactions table]

I want to de-normalize this table further to eliminate all repeated values. Arrays in BigQuery seem like a good candidate for this.

The below is close, but still returns repeated values in the second column.

```
select trans_id, array_agg(line_item_id), array_agg(part_id)
from transactions
group by 1
```

[image: attempt-1]

Further, the below is close as well, but now contains repeated values in the first column.

```
select trans_id, line_item_id, array_agg(part_id)
from transactions
group by 1, 2
```

[image: attempt-2]

Is there a straight-forward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT trans_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(line_item_id, parts)) items
FROM (
  SELECT trans_id, 
    line_item_id, 
    ARRAY_AGG(part_id) parts
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY trans_id, line_item_id
)
GROUP BY trans_id
```

When applied to sample data from your question - result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select trans_id, array_agg(distinct line_item_id), array_agg(part_id) as parts
from transactions t
group by trans_id;
```